# Verify client ID and Key OAuth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

In Microsoft Azure:
How can I verify these keys, without log in?

In my web I have valid keys with which validate users, but I want to verify that keys are corrects (without user interaction) before logged users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the process is explained on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx